# using intent to save which checkboxes were checked in different activity

Tags: android, android-intent

So in one activity I have a button .

clicking that button will initialize a different activity which has a list view , each view there contains list of checkboxes the user should choose from

(sort of like questions and multiple answers...)

thing is, when going back to previous activity I want the values of those checkboxes to be saved . 
I'm thinking intents are the way to do it but I'm not so sure how...

Comment: consider [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Answer (score 0):

Start Activity B by using [`startActiviyForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) in your button click listener.

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this);
         startActivityForResult(intent, 1234); // 1234 is used in callback
    }
});
```

In second activity:

For return data using back button, override [`onBackPressed()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed())

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent returnData = new Intent();
    // get data from checkboxes
    returnData.putExtra("key_1", data1);
    returnData.putExtra("key_2", data2);
    setResult(MainActivity.RESULT_OK, returnData);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

For return data using normal button, use something like this:

```
exitbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent returnData = new Intent();
         // get data from checkboxes
         returnData.putExtra("key_1", data1); 
         returnData.putExtra("key_2", data2);
         setResult(MainActivity.RESULT_OK, returnData);
         finish();
    }
});
```

If you want cancel second activity, `setResult(RESULT_CANCELED)`, instead RESULT_OK.

Then in MainActivity override [`onActivityResult()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)), it is the callback when second activity finishes.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1234) { // previous defined
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            int data1 = data.getIntExtra("key_1", 0); 
            int data2 = data.getIntExtra("key_2", 0); 
        }
    }
}
```

Strongly advice to read [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)

Comment: are you sure onSavedInstanceState isn't for saving the user's checked boxes in the same activity after he returns to it ?

Comment: what I need is for activity A (the activity from which I go to activity B) will retreive activity B's checked values

Comment: @yanivshe sorry if i misunderstood, you said *when going back to previous activity I want the values of those checkboxes to be saved*, but you want get a result set in activit A rigth?

Comment: sorry for the delay . what is data1 and data2 ?

Comment: but what if there are a lot of checkboxes?

Comment: @yanivshe Intent.putExtra have several forms, including arrays, serializable, and bundle.

Comment: You could create a int[] and fill it with all checked items from the adapter

Answer (score 0):

**in your activity A :**
start your activity B with startActivityForResult :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1); // intent and requestCode of 1
```

**in your activity B :**
get your checkBox values :

```
boolean isChecked = ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1)).isChecked(); // your check box value for example
```

then send your values back to the first activity :

```
public static final String FIRSTCHECKBOX = "first"; 
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra(FIRSTCHECKBOX, isChecked); // add all your check box values like this
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

if you want cancel it (such as user click on cancel btn) :

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
finish();
```

**again in your activity A :**
get your values :

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultIntent) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
              if (requestCode ==1) {
                  Bolean check1 =resultIntent.getBooleanExtra(FIRSTCHECKBOX,0)// do it for all other check boxes - 0 is defualt value that you can choose 0 or 1
              }
        }
```

}